# Multiple global filters in primefaces data tables

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have two primefaces dataTables on the same page and I need to add two global filters, one for each. But global filters only work if you the inputText id = "globalFilter". I cannot have two id's same as I get a duplicate id's error. Is there any work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, seems to be the correct behavior, following PrimeFaces API:

> Filter located at header is a global one applying on all fields, this
>   is implemented by calling client side API method called filter(),
>   important part is to specify the id of the input text as globalFilter
>   which is a reserved identifier for datatable

My workaround at that time was to put the inputText filters outside the datatables and then manually filter the queries with the desired value.